# CLOSE | Chrome Tab | Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Please help me with closing a Chrome Tab using Javascript.
I tried these - But all are failing.

```
open('about:blank', '_self').close(); - This opens up a new tab, and the user is able to browse back. Which is not required.
open(location, '_self').close(); - Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.
window.open('','_parent','');
window.close(); - Not working
```

Comment: So you don't want the user to be able to navigate back to a page, right? Closing the tab is not necessary.

Comment: so, you want your page to close the tab it is in? you can't

Comment: Nisarg,
Closing the Tab is necessary, as I need it Abort the session.

Comment: Jaromanda,
Means, its not possible ?

Comment: @Alanga Is any part of _Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it_ unclear?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know Chrome and Firefox have removed this feature of closing tab through JavaScript . Not sure about IE. Yet you can try this, it might work
(Remember you can only close those tabs which you yourself have opened through script) 
Try

windows.top.close();

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried - Not Working.
But any way, I need the feature. As to Kill the Session.My application is an Intranet application over AD network.

Or Suggest any other methodology, to Kill Intranet Applications' Session

Comment: Firefox 90.0.2 works for me with `<a href="javascript:close()">Close this tab.</a>`.